# issues with distribution profile on the iPad.... keeps crashing

Tags: iphone, ipad, profile

thanks for looking... any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

We are having issues loading an iPhone build onto the ipad for testing purposes. The build works fine in Debug mode on the simulator and on the device. When I switch to a distribution provisioning profile the app either does not accept any touches or crashes on startup.

We are not aiming for a universal application... We are not optimizing for iPad but we are making sure that it runs on the iPad as if it were an iPhone application.

The application works fine on the iPhone and the iPod touch with the distribution profile. We have tried remove all certifications and provisioning profiles from the device, macbook and the portal. None of it worked.

The Base SDK is set to iPhone Device 4.0
The iPhone OS Deplyoment Target is set to iPhone OS 3.0.

Any assistance you can provide will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When apps work on one device and in debug mode, but not on another device, I tend to suspect memory problems: out-of-memory, a leak, accessing a released object, writing past C array bounds, etc.  I would start by carefully checking the memory usage (iPad requires larger imageViews?), leaks, NSZombies, etc.

Comment: ill give that a try, but it crashes before it really does anything... the last version of the application is on the app store and that works fine on the iPad....  but ill check NSZombies